# PhoneGap Database Insert Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I have a PhoneGap app that takes a user prompt value and uploads that parameter to my company server. A process is kicked off that creates a chart and returns it to the app. The script is getting to the console.log() statement, but the executeSQL function is not working. I declare the database at the top, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm not getting any errors, but the value is not getting passed to the

```
var locationStr;

      window.gp_chart = new Geoprocessor("http://ourserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/Three_Week_Chart/GPServer/ThreeWeekChart");

      var link = domConstruct.create("a",{
            "class": "action", 
            "id": "chartLink",
            "innerHTML": "Three Week Chart", //text that appears in the popup for the link 
            "href": "javascript: void(0);"
          }, query(".actionList", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);

      on(link, "click", function()
            { 


             // database setup
            var db = window.openDatabase("myDB", "", "DB", 100000);

            window.navigator.notification.prompt(
              "Enter Location Name: ", // message
              handleLocationPrompt, // callback
              "Add location", //title
              ["Ok", "Exit"] // button titles
            );

            // handle user's dialog action
            function handleLocationPrompt(results) {
              if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {
                // Ok
                locationStr = results.input1
                addLocationToDB(locationStr);

              }
            }

            function addLocationToDB(locationStr){

              if (!locationStr) return; // don't add empty string
              // run query, pass success callback function as 3rd parameter
              console.log(locationStr);
              db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO cat (Name) VALUES (?)", [locationStr], querySuccess);
              });
            }

             var lat,lon = "";
             lat = x.toString();
             lon = y.toString();

            var taskParams = {
              "Latitude": lat,
              "Longitude": lon,
              "Location": locationStr
            };


            // handle successful db insertion
            function querySuccess() {
              domAttr.set(dom.byId("chartLink"), "innerHTML", "Generating Chart...");
              window.gp_chart.execute(taskParams, gpChartResultAvailable, gpChartFailure);
            }
```

Comment: `window.openDatabase()` creates a local SQLite database (local as in "on the phone"), inserting into it does not send anything to a server.

Comment: Sorry, the taskParams dict is uploaded to the server in the gp_chart.execute function. I just need to pass the prompt value to the taskParams. I need the server process to kick off only after the user prompt.

Comment: In that case you don't need to run any queries locally. Just do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jdkjqv5d/

Comment: x and y are defined earlier in the larger script. I dropped your example in and I got a gray screen and no errors. I've tried to make a callback function like your addLocationToDB example that just runs the gp_chart.execute but I always get a gray screen.

Comment: I added the entire script to the fiddle with a couple of minor changes. I'm still getting a gray screen.

Comment: In that case it's back to debugging 101: add `console.log(stuff)` commands in various places and see what gets executed and how.

Comment: I can't debug in Weinre when the app comes up as a gray screen. It says no target and there's nothing in the console. I've been dealing with this for a week, which is why I was trying the executeSQL approach

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works.

```
var locationStr;

      window.gp_chart = new Geoprocessor("http://ourserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/Three_Week_Chart/GPServer/ThreeWeekChart");

      var link = domConstruct.create("a",{
            "class": "action", 
            "id": "chartLink",
            "innerHTML": "Three Week Chart", //text that appears in the popup for the link 
            "href": "javascript: void(0);"
          }, query(".actionList", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);

      on(link, "click", function()
            { 

            window.navigator.notification.prompt(
              "Enter Location Name: ", // message
              handleLocationPrompt, // callback
              "Add location", //title
              ["Ok", "Exit"] // button titles
            );

            // handle user's dialog action
            function handleLocationPrompt(results) {
              if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {
                // Ok
                locationStr = results.input1

                var lat,lon = "";
             lat = x.toString();
             lon = y.toString();

            var taskParams = {
              "Latitude": lat,
              "Longitude": lon,
              "Location": locationStr

            };
              domAttr.set(dom.byId("chartLink"), "innerHTML", "Generating Chart...");
              window.gp_chart.execute(taskParams, gpChartResultAvailable, gpChartFailure);


              }
            }
```